# How to programmatically access {{ form.my_field.id_for_label }}?

Tags: django, django-forms

My Django project uses Bootstrap v4.

I iterate through all the fields to add the HTML attribute `class="form-control"`. I also need to add an HTML attribute `aria-describedby="{}Help"` where `{}` is the `id_for_label` for the widget.

In the template language I could print that value easily with `{{ form.my_field.id_for_label }}` but programmatically I don't know how to do it.

I tried it with `ModelForm().fields['…'].widget.id_for_label()` but that method expects an argument. And by lookind at the Django source code, the return value is literally the argument.

Any ideas?

```
class AbonnentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Abonnent
        fields = '__all__'



    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AbonnentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Add Bootstrap class to all <input> elements.
        for key, value in self.fields.items():
            value.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})

            if value.help_text:
                id_for_label = "{}Help".format(value.widget.id_for_label())
                value.widget.attrs.update({'aria-describedby': id_for_label})

        self.fields['erste_ausgabe'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder':'MM/JJJJ'})
        self.fields['letzte_ausgabe'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder':'MM/JJJJ'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can contruct it yourself like this:

```
for key, value in self.fields.items():
     value.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})

     if value.help_text:
         django_id_for_label = self.auto_id % key  # self.auto_id == 'id_%s'
         my_id_for_label = '{}Help'.format(django_id_for_label)
         value.widget.attrs.update({'aria-describedby': my_id_for_label})
```